# How to customize django-allauth urls

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth, custom-url

I want to change the default django-allauth urls with my custom one, for example:
Instead of accessing /accounts/login I want to acces login page: /mylogin.
I tried to modify urls.py but it doesn't have a complete result.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from allauth.account.views import LoginView, SignupView 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    path('mylogin/', LoginView.as_view(), name='custom_login'),
    path('myregister/', SignupView.as_view(), name='custom_reg'),
]
```

Comment: What do you mean  "doesn't have a complete result."?

Comment: I solved the problem. I also changed the urls in all templates that redirect to login/register with my custom urls names. Much easier than I expected